# Is this black spot on roselle leaf fungal?

Tags: diseases

I have had one leaf which had two of these black spots. Now this is the second one where I have one blackish spot (Pic 1).
Is this due to fungi? It seems to be embedded in the leaf.

Otherwise, in two other leaves there were yellowish black spots. I have cut away these ones. (Pic 2)

Please suggest remedies too since we have an essentials-only lockdown here so can't get any fungicide.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might consider hydrogen peroxide as a remedy and a test. It's a natural substance which will not harm your plant and might be readily available from a pharmacy even in a lockdown, or from a neighbour's medicine cabinet. If the spots continue after this treatment then it will likely not be fungus so keep an eye open for insects, research the quality of the irrigation water and ensure occasional balanced fertilizer if using a peat based compost.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a 100% sure but this could be downy/powdery mildew.

I don't really know how to treat it in your situation though.